# How often should saving to disk occur in an automatically saving text editor?

Tags: applications, file-handling

I am developing a simple text editor and would like the application to save the text automatically. In other words, the user would never have to press a save button.

I have seen other applications that do this, and was wondering how often is it safe to write files to disk? From a user experience standpoint, it seems that the more frequently this happens the better, but I am worried about performance and possible disk wear (especially on writes to SSDs). It seems like the operating system disk caching might help avoid these problems, but I also don't know if its safe to rely on that for an application like this.

I was planning on writing the whole document to disk at each save, but this just seems terribly inefficient if the OS ends up writing it to disk to frequently, but relying on program unload may lose data in the case of a crash.

Does anyone have any experience dealing with this that might be able to help?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: Impossible to say. Set a default but make it configurable.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of factors that go into the determine what frequency makes sense. You have already mentioned some of them. It's highly unlikely that you will fine a single value that makes sense for all cases.

What you should do it make the value configurable. The application doesn't care how frequently a save happens, just that it happens. Once you have this in place, you can test it and try to tune the value. Since you are dealing with human interaction, the delay between required number of disc writes will seem like an eternity to the computer.

Even after you have arrived at what you feel is a good default, you should still leave the value as configurable. You might have a user that has a different preference than you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't over-analyze this to the point that you're worrying about hardware.  A basic approach would be to maintain a 'modified' flag.  Then automatically save after the program is idle for some number of seconds - but only if the text has been modified.  Once the text is saved, clear the modified flag, and repeat the process.

Comment: You do not want to autosave only when the user has been idle for a time. If I begin working in a text and don't stop for thirty minutes, in the event of a crash I would lose far more work than an user that wrote a line and went somewhere else... yet I would be less protected.

Comment: @SJuan76 I'm curious how you managed to interpret *some number of seconds* to mean 30 minutes.

Comment: I think the sense of the comment is obvious(the "don't stop working" part), but I will write it slower for you. As per your description, your process will prevent the program from autosaving as long as the user is active. If you set it up to save only after 20 seconds of inactivity and I press a key each 10 seconds, the program will never autosave. Unless the document is a CAD design, current HW is more than capable of saving the document even if the user is typing.

Comment: @SJuan76 and you *actually* think someone is going to sit and type for 30 minutes, non-stop, without ever taking 5 to 10 seconds occasionally to stop and think about what to write next?  Do you *really* think that's how users use text editors?  I'd hate to see your code if that's the way you work.  And if 10 seconds works out to be too long... why can't it be set to 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

> I was planning on writing the whole document to disk at each save, but this just seems terribly inefficient if the OS ends up writing it to disk to frequently, but relying on program unload may lose data in the case of a crash

What many editors do (v.g. Word) is just writting the entire document to another, temporary location and, once the file is written to disk, just change the name to the default one. After an application crash, if I find the temp file, I can check if it is consistent and proceed accordingly. If the temp file was damaged, I still have the original one.

That said, the idea of overwritting my previous document version without my consent is a terrible one, IM(ns)HO. First, because it is not the behavior users expect. And second, because it forbids them from deciding if the changes done to the document are worth saving or not. At worst, you auto-save feature will run after a user selected some (or all) of the document for applying an style and inadvertently pushed "Del".

Comment: I agree with your opinions on this behavior. The application I am working on is designed for taking notes, and version control will be implemented as well to avoid similar situations to what you have described. I have used applications like this before that have frustrated me due to me doing exactly what you have described. Now I am experimenting with it to see if I can do it in a way that works for me :-)

Comment: I think you're grossly over (or maybe under?) simplifying it. Users don't expect this behavior only because we've been teaching them wrong for so long - we undid centuries of experience where, when you made a change to a document it was immediately changed. And the solution for whether the information is worth saving -- and likely 99+% of the time it is -- is to optimize for for the normal case of saving. The 1% (or maybe .001%) of the time you decide not to save your work there should be an easy undo or revert to some point back in time.

Comment: @BryanOakley indeed, IntelliJ saves on the fly, don't know the interval but it's often. You very quickly get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach: why not build your text editor like a transactional database? Instead of writing the whole document, make a backup copy once a document is loaded or saved (as a "reference document") and create a [transaction log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log), where only the key strokes and menu commands are recorded. Write these commands continously to disk (which can be done quick, immediately and in the background), so in case of a system crash, you can always reconstructed the last working state by loading the last reference doc and re-apply all commands from the trans log.